# Java Code - perform memory profiling remotely

Tags: java

I am running a Java code in a server (remotely) by using javac. Now, I want to perform memory profiling remotely because as [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/index.jsp) say's,

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:
Cannot start the profiler UI: display is not available on this machine.
```

Can anybody help me how can I do this easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use JProfiler.You can get it from [here](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) and found many helpful tutorials.Here is JProfiler [manual](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/help.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

If your server starts with YourKit profiler agent (according to the output) you just need to start YourKit profiler UI and connect it to the remote profiler agent. There is "Monitor Remote Applications" on profiler start screen

Here is the direct links to YourKit help:

http://www.yourkit.com/docs/11/help/profiling_j2ee_remote.jsp

Comment: [Per the faq's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion), please be sure to disclose your affiliation with products you are recommending in all responses.

Comment: Leigh, my affiliation with YourKit is specified in my profile. As you see in the post I'm not recommending, but answering on question about YourKit profiler. Sure, I'll specify affiliation when I recommend or advertise =)

Comment: All fair points. But disclosure is not solely about promotion. Doing so also gives additional credibility to your responses. ie Given that you are involved with the product, chances are you may be more knowledgeable about it than the average person responding =) Since not everyone reads profiles, that is good information for a reader to have.

Answer (score 0):

This is exact what is happening in our pre-production env...

actually if you want to launch the YourkitUI on remote machine directly, the way I am currently doing it is using Xmanager->xshell http://www.netsarang.com/products/xmg_overview.html
You also need to install X-server as precondition. You will be able to run any kind of UI remotely, not only yourkit.

also make sure your yourkit launch conf like this

```
-agentpath:$YOURKIT_HOME/bin/linux-x86-64/libyjpagent.so=disablestacktelemetry,
disableexceptiontelemetry,builtinprobes=none,delay=20000,sessionname=jboss-pre-prod
```

Answer (score -1):

[your kit remote profiling](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/10/help/attach_wizard.jsp)

if this helps you. If this process is not helping may be we can think of any other option.